# Support multiple inputs JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm learning how to develop a game in html/css3/javascript/jquery and i have to support multiple keyboard inputs.

By following a book, i have written this code:

```
var pingpong = {};

pingpong.pressedKeys = [];

$(function() {
    // set interval to call gameloop every 30 milliseconds
    pingpong.timer = setInterval(gameloop, 30);
    // mark down what key is down and up into an array called
    // "pressedKeys"
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        pingpong.pressedKeys[e.which] = true;
    });

    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        pingpong.pressedKeys[e.which] = false;
    });
});

function gameloop() {
    movePaddles();
}

function movePaddles() {
    // use our custom timer to continuously check if a key is
    // pressed.
    if (pingpong.pressedKeys[KEY.UP]) {// arrow-up
        // move the paddle B up 5 pixels
        var top = parseInt($("#paddleB").css("top"));
        $("#paddleB").css("top", top - 5);
    }
    if (pingpong.pressedKeys[KEY.DOWN]) {// arrow-down
        // move the paddle B down 5 pixels
        var top = parseInt($("#paddleB").css("top"));
        $("#paddleB").css("top", top + 5);
    }
    if (pingpong.pressedKeys[KEY.W]) {// w
        // move the paddle A up 5 pixels
        var top = parseInt($("#paddleA").css("top"));
        $("#paddleA").css("top", top - 5);
    }
    if (pingpong.pressedKeys[KEY.S]) {// s
        // move the paddle A down 5 pixels
        var top = parseInt($("#paddleA").css("top"));
        $("#paddleA").css("top", top + 5);
    }
}
```

But it does not work. I mean, the paddles don't move! Any idea?

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>MyGame</title>
        <style>
            #playground {
                background: #e0ffe0;
                width: 400px;
                height: 200px;
                position: relative;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #ball {
                background: #fbb;
                position: absolute;
                width: 20px;
                height: 20px;
                left: 150px;
                top: 100px;
                border-radius: 10px;
            }
            .paddle {
                background: #bbf;
                left: 50px;
                top: 70px;
                position: absolute;
                width: 30px;
                height: 70px;
            }
            #paddleB {
                left: 320px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Test</h1>
        </header>
        <div id="game">
            <div id="playground">
                <div id="paddleA" class="paddle"></div>
                <div id="paddleB" class="paddle"></div>
                <div id="ball"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            This is an example of creating a Game.
        </footer>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
        <script src="js/html5games.pingpong.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**MyGoal**

Move with S (down) and W (up) the left paddle, and with arrow up (UP) and arrow down (down) the right paddle. If i press S AND arrow down, the left paddle must move up, and the right paddle must move down, AT THE SAME TIME. (The events must not stop each other).

**What i get**

The keyboard input does not work. The paddles don't move.

**UPDATE**

I forgot to add this to the .js code:

```
var KEY = {
    UP : 38,
    DOWN : 40,
    W : 87,
    S : 83
};
```

Comment: Share all other relevant code (HTML, etc) and explain your problem giving more details. `But it does not work. I mean, the paddles don't move!` is not sufficient.

Comment: You're right, i edited the message.

Comment: [You simply added the HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31648377/revisions) but haven't provided us with more information on what you're getting and what is expected. Please be specific.

Comment: Now it should be clear.

Comment: The first thing I see is that your keydown and keyup are going to conflict.  You are simply saving the array value as true or false but if you click righ-arrow and the value gets saved to the array with 'true' on key down, then on key up it goes back to 'false'.  the only way anything would happen is if the timer hit the next section right between the key down and key up events.

Comment: If i click W, then pressedKeys[e.which] = true and in movePaddles() the if condition if (pingpong.pressedKeys[KEY.W]) should be satisfied.

Comment: Is there a KEY object defined in the library you're using or is it defined somewhere else? Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: I forgot to create a KEY array, i'm totally idiot